# Installing SSL certificate and configure FQDN on Ubuntu 14

Tags: apache2, ssl

I have installed Ubuntu. Below is my server version

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

After that I install Apache and PHP5 on it. After that I install php files in /var/www/html folder.

Now I have wild card SSL certificate which is provided by verisign. Certificate request was generated from Windows server. Verisign has provided me two crt files IntermediateCA and ssl_certificate.  Can somebody tell me how can I install

I also want to add full URL to my apache how can I do that.

Hope somebody can give me reply.

Comment: You did not generate the key + csr on the server involved, but instead on a different server? Then you need to first get the private key before you can do anything with the certificate on a server. And please include your current Apache site configuration. And please [edit] your question on what you have tried and what failed. Because this is a very basic question.

Comment: from where can I get private key

Comment: Well, you must have generated a private key before you can create a CSR... (with a CSR the CA creates the certiticate for you). Please include the *exact* steps you followed... but if you did this on a Windows machine, it's offtopic here I guess. And you should **never generate a key on another machine**, always do it on the machine you are requesting a certificate for, because you need to keep your private key private. That's the whole idea of SSL/TLS in the first place (security).

Comment: As I told you I have certificate ready to install, which was already requested from Windows Server. As it is wildcard certificate, I am interested to install on ubuntu server and verisign already provide me unbutu compatible certificate

Comment: Sorry to downvote your question, but you appear not to understand the basics here. A certificate complements a private key. The certificate is created based on the certificate request (CSR) which in turn is derived from the private key. The public key in your certificate is cryptographically "paired" with the generated private key. Without access to your private key, the certificate is useless. And again, please show in your question what you have tried already. Installing SSL certificates with Apache is a very very common practice which is very well documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for @gertvdijk pointing me to right direction. As I told you I had generated CSR from windows server and also certificate was install on windows server. So I did as below

1. I exported my certificate to pfx file
2. Then copied pfx file Ubuntu server
3. Then I use this command `openssl pkcs12 -in file.pfx -out file.pem`
4. When this step is complete, I have a PEM file that I can read in a text editor. Open the file in a text editor and copy the private key and certificate to different files. Remember to keep the dashed lines intact when you copy the certificates – this is important. There is some additional text above the key, and also between the key and certificate – this text should be ignored and should not be included in the certificate and key files.
5. Now that I have the key and certificate separated, I need to decrypt the private key (or face the wrath of Apache every time you restart the server). You can decrypt the private key like this:
   `openssl rsa -in file.key -out file.key`
6. Then I make directory by `sudo mkdir /etc/apache2/ssl`
7. Copied my SSL, PrivateKey and Intermidate crt files in that directory
8. Then I add this in my configuration file

[image]